# Page Authentication in Silverlight 4 Navigation Application

Tags: sql, wcf, silverlight, navigation

I'm pretty much a newbie in programming C# and I've been looking for quite some time now.

I need help with page authentication in a Silverlight navigation application.

I have a SQL Database running and a WCF service that gets the credentials out of that database. When the user is logged in he needs to see a link in the upper right corner with his profile.

How can I do this without using any help from silverlight? Is this even possible? Can I write a class that says "this user is authenticated and can see the following pages" on my own?

This is a really urgent issue. So thanks in advance for anyone's help!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly use AspNet Membership ,
Most of classes you need implemented yet. 
This link shows you how to setup membershipt tables to your SQL Server DB.

http://weblogs.asp.net/sukumarraju/archive/2009/10/02/installing-asp-net-membership-services-database-in-sql-server-expreess.aspx

In membership struct you can register,delete, lock - unlock ,store user details operations,... and more easier.
Here is an article explains implementation of membership for you,

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kylemc/archive/2010/05/10/using-asp-net-membership-in-silverlight.aspx